# How to display an element of an array from .js file in .html paragraph

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, paragraph

I'm trying to make a javascript function that displays different string every 7 days for example. And I want to display that string in a footer of an html.
The part that bugs me is how to insert that string in a paragraph in html (or anything that will display the text).
I have 2 dimensional array in .js, let's say:

```
array = [[first1,first2],[second1,second2],[third1,third2],[fourth1,fourth2],[fifth1,fifth2]];
```

And I want do display, let's say

```
array[2][0] in one paragraph and
array[2][1] in another paragraph.
```

let's say

```
<div>
    <p>In here i want array[2][0]</p>
    <p>In here i want array[2][1]</p>
</div>
```

Please help.

Comment: For the purpose of the task, I should only use JavaScript and HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div>
    <p>In here i want <span id="placeholder-1"></span></p>
    <p>In here i want <span id="placeholder-2"></span></p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById('placeholder-1').innerHTML = array[2][0];
document.getElementById('placeholder-2').innerHTML = array[2][1];
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8N95j/

Comment: this didn't work. and i imported .js file in html, and did everything like you did

Comment: And does the fiddle work? If copy-pasting didn't work it's possible there are some things you could learn, but without seeing your code I can't really help. My bet is you included the JavaScript higher in the document than the `span`s you want to modify.

Comment: well i included it in the head with <script scr =...></src>

Comment: those third1 and third2 are already strings, for example:
third1 = "Some text here";
third2 = "Some text there";

Comment: @Miroslav that's what I guessed. The script executes while it's being parsed and if it's in the `<head>` the elements it wants to modify are not in the document yet, because it's still loading. Move the `<script src...>` all the way down before `</body>`.

Answer (score 0):

select the html element by `document.getElementById/getElementsByClassName` and attach the js value like

```
var ele = document.getElementById('footerid');
ele.innerHTML += array[2][0];
```

**note:** `getElementsByClassName` would give u an array

#### update

here is a [**working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/TdTsb/) using the same markup u shared.

Answer (score 0):

One different approach would be to use a framework like Ember or AngularJS. These are quite easy to put in place nowadays, and leads to much easier to maintain code. For instance, your HTML would look like

```
<div ng-controller='MyController'>
    <p>In here i want {{ array[2][0] }}</p>
    <p>In here i want {{ array[2][1] }}</p>
</div>
```

where MyController references an AngularJS controller (basically a simple javascript object which defines a $scope in which the array is defined.

At that point, you no longer need to update the HTML, ever. Whenever your javascript does something like  array[2][0] = 'foo'   the HTML is automatically updated in real-time.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to dynamically create a p tag and append it in a container div

HTML :

```
 <div id="container">
   <p>In here i want Test1</p>
</div>
```

JS :

```
    var array = [['first1','first2'],['second1','second2'],['third1','third2'],['fourth1','fourth2'],['fifth1','fifth2']];

   //If needed for loop can start here
    var para = document.createElement("p");
    para.innerHTML = 'In here i want ' + array[2][0];
    document.getElementById('container').appendChild(para);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/karan3112/8N95j/1/)